# Token CSRF só é válido após primeira requisição ajax

Tags: php, token, token-ajax

Estou construindo um sistema de login via ajax e usando um token, guardando em uma **SESSION**, passado por javascript, a ideia é que a cada "reload" de página seja criado um novo token para evitar brute-force e etc, só que como estou enviando via ajax, o token só é válido na primeira requisição, se o usuário errar o usuário/senha o token fica inválido e não é possível mais fazer login mesmo colocando os dados corretos, como posso contornar essa situação?

Comment: Como você está atribuindo o valor do token no formulário?

Comment: Declarei uma variável global javascript no header que vem do php, não coloquei num input porque dessa forma evita brute-force.

Comment: Tenho minhas duvidas de quão útil isso é para brute-force. Basta que o atacante pegue o token e envie. Seria necessário o dobro de requisições (e dependendo da construção, uma delas poderia ser uma requisição HEAD, o que iria ser ainda mais rápido), mas nem de longe iria evitar. Para evitar brute-force acho que somente criando Rate-Limit. Para aumentar o custo poderia adicionar alguns captcha e adicionar um 2FA junto a senha, assim o atacante teria que acertar duas informações ao invés de somente a senha. Enfim, o CSRF-Token para mim deve ser somente contra CSRF, nada mais do que ele.

Comment: Se estiver preocupado com o próprio brute-force de CSRF (tentar acertar um CRSF), acredito que isso não seria um problema. Se você por exemplo gerar um _token_ com 128 bits já seria suficiente, se quiser usar um `random_bytes(64)` (512 bits) já seria muito mais do que suficiente. Desde de que compare de maneira segura (`hash_equals`) o atacante terá que procurar por todas as possibilidades mesmo. A questão talvez seja outras vulnerabilidades, como por exemplo o Session Fixation, daí o atacante já saberia qual o CSRF-Token o outro usuário tem e etc.

Comment: Pra evitar testes de SQL também, já que o token está no javascript e não no input do html, o sqlmap ,por exemplo,captura do html, quando é colocado no javascript fica praticamente impossível testar.

Comment: muitos programas de brute-force seguem a mesma lógica, só capturam dados que estão diretamente em campos de formulário no  html

Comment: Se sua preocupação for "programas" de fato isso pode dificultar, mas quem usará isso são pessoas com pouco conhecimento, _Script Kiddie_. Mas qualquer pessoa com mais de conhecimento conseguirá obter os dados do javascript e replicar a requisição, esta deveria ser a maior preocupação ao meu ver. Enganar verificações automáticas é fácil, tanto que até hoje existem empresas especializadas em auditoria de códigos/pentest, executadas por um humano. O que evita SQL Injection não é o CSRF-Token, nunca foi e nunca será.

Comment: Eu sei,mas só o fato de colocar os campos em teste, já gera muita requisição ao servidor.